# Copying the adjacent cell text of Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to have a Macro in Microsoft Word in which I search for a specified word in Excel (a name for example), but copy the text of the cell at the right (email). This is what I've done trying to solve the problem:

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application, xlWkBk As Excel.Workbook
Dim StrWkBkNm As String, StrWkShtNm As String, LRow As Long, i As Long
StrWkBkNm = ActiveDocument.Path & "\BD.xlsx"
StrWkShtNm = "Hoja2"
With xlApp
  Set xlWkBk = .Workbooks.Open(StrWkBkNm) '''''''''''''''''''
  With xlWkBk
      With .Worksheets(StrWkShtNm)
        .Cells.Find(What:="Prueba", After:=ActiveCell, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Selection.Copy
      End With
    .Close False
  End With
  .Quit
End With
Selection.Paste
```

For example, I need to search for the name "AAAA", but copy aaaa@gmail.com" in the word document. See the image for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: Please also explain how the code provided is not working.

Comment: FYI, when posting sample data, please post it **as text**, so people can copy/paste it for testing purposes.  You can always include an image as well, if you think it adds additional value

Comment: @Cindy, err, ... they did, kind of (_but copy the text of the cell at the right (email)_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a different approach, try:

```
Sub BulkFindReplace()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim xlApp As Object, xlWkBk As Object, StrWkBkNm As String, StrWkSht As String
Dim iDataRow As Long, xlFList As String, xlRList As String, i As Long
StrWkBkNm = ActiveDocument.Path & "\BD.xlsx"
StrWkSht = "Hoja2"
If Dir(StrWkBkNm) = "" Then
  MsgBox "Cannot find the designated workbook: " & StrWkBkNm, vbExclamation
  Exit Sub
End If
On Error Resume Next
'Start Excel
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
If xlApp Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "Can't start Excel.", vbExclamation
  Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
With xlApp
  'Hide our Excel session
  .Visible = False
  ' The file is available, so open it.
  Set xlWkBk = .Workbooks.Open(FileName:=StrWkBkNm, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMru:=False)
  If xlWkBk Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Cannot open:" & vbCr & StrWkBkNm, vbExclamation
    .Quit: Set xlApp = Nothing: Exit Sub
  End If
  ' Process the workbook.
  With xlWkBk
    With .Worksheets(StrWkSht)
      ' Find the last-used row in column A.
      iDataRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row ' -4162 = xlUp
      ' Capture the F/R data.
      For i = 1 To iDataRow
        ' Skip over empty fields to preserve the underlying cell contents.
        If Trim(.Range("A" & i)) <> vbNullString Then
          xlFList = xlFList & "|" & Trim(.Range("A" & i))
          xlRList = xlRList & "|" & Trim(.Range("B" & i))
        End If
      Next
    End With
  .Close False
  End With
  .Quit
End With
' Release Excel object memory
Set xlWkBk = Nothing: Set xlApp = Nothing
'Exit if there are no data
If xlFList = "" Then Exit Sub
'Process each word from the F/R List
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .MatchWholeWord = True
  .MatchCase = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  For i = 1 To UBound(Split(xlFList, "|"))
    .Text = Split(xlFList, "|")(i)
    .Replacement.Text = Split(xlRList, "|")(i)
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

With the above code, you don't need to specify the search term - the macro simply processes all potential terms in column A and replaces them with the corresponding email addresses from Column B (you can change the column references if you wish).

As coded, the email addresses are inserted as simple text strings. If you want them to be formatted as hyperlinks, insert:

```
'Get current autoformat options
With Options
  bHead = .AutoFormatApplyHeadings
  bList = .AutoFormatApplyLists
  bBullet = .AutoFormatApplyBulletedLists
  bOther = .AutoFormatApplyOtherParas
  bQuote = .AutoFormatReplaceQuotes
  bSymbol = .AutoFormatReplaceSymbols
  bOrdinal = .AutoFormatReplaceOrdinals
  bFraction = .AutoFormatReplaceFractions
  bEmphasis = .AutoFormatReplacePlainTextEmphasis
  bHLink = .AutoFormatReplaceHyperlinks
  bStyle = .AutoFormatPreserveStyles
  bMail = .AutoFormatPlainTextWordMail
  bTag = .LabelSmartTags
End With
'Restrict autoformat options to emails
With Options
  .AutoFormatApplyHeadings = False
  .AutoFormatApplyLists = False
  .AutoFormatApplyBulletedLists = False
  .AutoFormatApplyOtherParas = False
  .AutoFormatReplaceQuotes = False
  .AutoFormatReplaceSymbols = False
  .AutoFormatReplaceOrdinals = False
  .AutoFormatReplaceFractions = False
  .AutoFormatReplacePlainTextEmphasis = False
  .AutoFormatReplaceHyperlinks = False
  .AutoFormatPreserveStyles = False
  .AutoFormatPlainTextWordMail = True
  .LabelSmartTags = False
End With
```

after:

```
If xlFList = "" Then Exit Sub
```

and insert:

```
'Restore the original autoformat options
With Options
  .AutoFormatApplyHeadings = bHead
  .AutoFormatApplyLists = bList
  .AutoFormatApplyBulletedLists = bBullet
  .AutoFormatApplyOtherParas = bOther
  .AutoFormatReplaceQuotes = bQuote
  .AutoFormatReplaceSymbols = bSymbol
  .AutoFormatReplaceOrdinals = bOrdinal
  .AutoFormatReplaceFractions = bFraction
  .AutoFormatReplacePlainTextEmphasis = bEmphasis
  .AutoFormatReplaceHyperlinks = bHLink
  .AutoFormatPreserveStyles = bStyle
  .AutoFormatPlainTextWordMail = bMail
  .LabelSmartTags = bTag
End With
```

before:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: use `.Offset(0, 1)` to get the cell to the right

Longer answer: there is a lot of opportunity for improvement here

Consider this refactor of your code:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application, xlWkBk As Excel.Workbook, xlWkSh As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim WkBkNm As String, WkShtNm As String
    Dim WorkerColumn As Long
    Dim SearchTerm As String

    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    WkBkNm = ActiveDocument.Path & "\BD.xlsx"
    WkShtNm = "Hoja2"
    SearchTerm = "Prueba"
    WorkerColumn = 1 'Update this

    With xlApp
        On Error Resume Next
            Set xlWkBk = .Workbooks.Open(WkBkNm)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If xlWkBk Is Nothing Then
            ' File failed to open, what now?
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
            Set xlWkSh = xlWkBk.Worksheets(WkShtNm)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If xlWkSh Is Nothing Then
            ' Worksheet doesn't exist, what now?
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If
        With xlWkSh
            ' you should limit the search to the Worker column
            Set rng = .Columns(WorkerColumn).Find( _
              What:=SearchTerm, _
              After:=Excel.Cells(1, WorkerColumn), _
              LookAt:=Excel.xlPart, _
              SearchOrder:=Excel.xlByColumns, _
              SearchDirection:=Excel.xlNext, _
              MatchCase:=False, _
              SearchFormat:=False)
            ' test for value not found
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                rng.Offset(0, 1).Copy ' offset to get next column
                Word.Selection.Paste  'disambiguate
            End If
        End With
    End With
CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not xlWkBk Is Nothing Then xlWkBk.Close False
    xlApp.Quit
End Sub
```